# angular 2 website - enable touch

Tags: angular, web-applications, touch, long-press

I am developing an angular 2 website which has drag and drop feature. The user will be able to drag and drop divs to different places on the page. This is working fine on the computer since the user will use a mouse or touch pad.

However, on tablets and mobile phones, I'd like the user to be able to perform the same operation using touch (may be long press to select).

What libraries integrate with angular 2 to make a website touch enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by incorporating hammerjs.
Some references:
http://hammerjs.github.io/

https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying something like this: https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch

I haven't tried such a polyfill myself yet but from I've heard it's the only work around for now since mobile browsers does not support the drag and drop API consistently ATM.